# remove all sequences containg phrase "random"

Tags: replace, sed, awk, fasta

This is how my input looks like:

```
>a
AACTCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
>b_random
ACTGSTSTS
CTCTCTCCT
ATATATA
>c
AACTCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
>d
AACTCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
>e_random
ACTGSTSTS
CTCTCTCCT
ATATATA
>c_random
ACTGSTSTS
CTCTCTACT
GSTSTSCTC
TCTCCTCCT
ATATATA
```

I would like to remove all sequences containing phrase "random" - sequence always starts with ">" and ends when another sequence starts.

In this case, I would like to get 3 files:

a.txt

```
>a
AACTCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
```

c.txt

```
>c
AACTCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
```

d.txt

```
>d
AACTCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
CGTGCTCTC
```

Right now, I somehow can not force sed to do what I want. i started with this:

```
 sed 's/random.*random//g' sample_data
```

what is not working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to go here is probably with awk and a sensible RS/ORS setting:

```
awk '$1 !~ /random/ { print RS $0 > $1 ".txt"; close($1 ".txt" }' RS='>' ORS=''
```

If you have description lines with spaces in them, you need to set `FS='\n'` as well.

Comment: Omg. It's brilliant. What can I do to write such scripts by myself when I grow up? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Perlnika: Glad it works for you. To write such scripts you need practice. I've learned awk by reading tutorials (most recently [this one](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)), using it and studying how other people use it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with my biggest dataset: awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767 (The file is of the size 3.4 GB)

Comment: @Perlnika: Which version of awk are you using? Does setting `FS='\n'` help?

Comment: @Perlnika: It probably will not, using a recent version of GNU awk might. Otherwise use an approach that only reads one line at a time as _steve's_ and _srathi's_ answers do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `awk` that should handle large files:

```
awk '/^>/ { i=substr($0,2) } i ~ /random/ { i="" } i { print > i ".txt" }' file
```

Results of `grep . *.txt`:

```
a.txt:>a
a.txt:AACTCTCTC
a.txt:CGTGCTCTC
c.txt:>c
c.txt:AACTCTCTC
c.txt:CGTGCTCTC
d.txt:>d
d.txt:AACTCTCTC
d.txt:CGTGCTCTC
d.txt:CGTGCTCTC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working :-) I can immediately see newly created files.

Comment: You might want to close opened files along the way, so as not to run out of file descriptors. I think an `if(i) close(i ".txt")` in the `/^>/` block should do.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/\>/ && $0!~/random/{file=substr($0,2)".txt";f=1}{if($0~/random/)f=0;if(f)print>file}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk without using RS to avoid limitations

```
awk -F\> '/>/{close(f); f=/random/?x:$2 ".txt"} f{print>f}' file
```

This version also closes the file and uses a variable for the file name, because some awks cannot handle concatenated print targets.